# worklight adapter using restful webservice

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using worklight adapter to implementing on restful web service. but i can not get any successful response.

This is my adapter:

```
    function getTest(username,password) {
        var path = "http://test.mybluemix.net";
        var request = 'username='+username+'&'+'password='+password;
        var input = {
                method : 'get',
                returnedContentType : 'plain',
                path : path,
                headers: {
                    "Host":"http://test.mybluemix.net"
                },
                body : {
                    contentType: 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
                    content: request.toString()
                }
            };
            return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    }
```

this i got response for when i call the adapter..

> response header is connection close and X-Backside-Transport is failed

normally i have to hit above the url its working fine http://test.mybluemix.net/?username=sssss&password=dffa

```
response :   {"ID":"5","USERNAME":"sassad","PASSWORD":"adsa","ROLE":"abc","PHONENUMBER":"12345678"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things look wrong to me.

1. The `path` variable should not point to the hostname. It's supposed to be the part afterwards:

   In the adapter XML file you define the protocol, host and port values.
   Then you provide the path, for example: `http://myhost:8080/THE-PATH`. In this case I don't think you need it since according to your working URL example there is no actual path - there are only the parameters, the request.
2. I'm not sure you need the `host` header. Try w/out it first...

Try this. Hopefully that'll work.

```
function getTest(username,password) {
        var request = 'username='+username+'&'+'password='+password;
        var input = {
                method : 'get',
                returnedContentType : 'plain',
                path : path,
                //headers: {
                //   "Host":"http://test.mybluemix.net"
                // },
                body : {
                    contentType: 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
                    content: request.toString()
                }
            };
            return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
    }
```

Comment: yes bro i tried above that one is not working i am getting error for X-Backside-Transport failed and also connection close and config the url for xml file